# Java connection to database

Tags: java, sql

I have exhausted all avenues to sort out this problem, but to no avail. I have installed "SQL Management Studio 2012" and created a dummy database and methods, but I'm still getting a "null point exception pointer". Java and JDBC is set under user variables.

Here are the screen shots and code.

```
Static {
        // standard code to open a connection and statement to SQL Server database
        try {
            // Create a variable for the connection string.
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQL-SERVER;"
                    + "databaseName=ItunesDB;integratedSecurity=true;";

            // Establish the connection.
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        } // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("Sql Exception :" + sqle.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String listAll() {
        String output = "";
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable");
            while (res.next()) { // there is a result
                // the name field is the thrid one in the ResultSet
                // Note that with  ResultSet we count the fields starting from 1
                output += res.getString(1) + " " + res.getString(2) + " - "
                        + res.getString(3) + " " + res.getString(4) + " "
                        + res.getString(5) + "\n";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
        return output;
    }


public static String getName(String key) {
        try {

             SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE key = '04'      
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LibraryTable WHERE ID = '" + key + "'");
            if (res.next()) { // there is a result
                // the name field is the second one in the ResultSet
                // Note that with  ResultSet we count the fields starting from 1
                return res.getString(2);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }`enter code here`
```

The database information:

```
Dummy Database
ID Name Artist Quantity Price Rating Playcount
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: where u get null pointer exception ??

Comment: Where is the NPE?  Stack traces would be helpful.

Comment: The moment another class within my program is trying to check track lists .Apparently it was working before adding SQL code in my library  class .

Answer (score 0):

Re install sql server in mixed mode . Then go to SQL Server configuration manager and checks is the TCP/Ip is enable . IF not enable it and restart the service. Then add sqljdbc jar in your project . Then try this code

```
Connection con = null;
  try {

     Class.forName(
    "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(
      "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
    + "user=sa;password=HerongYang;"
    + "database=AdventureWorksLT");
  }
```

user is always sa because it is the system administrator

Comment: Thank you very much I will follow your instructions and will return with a feed back .